# undefined reference to nids_run

Tags: eclipse

I want to use libnids library in my program and
I've just included 'nids.h' without any problem .

but in building process (using Eclipse as IDE) , it has an error  :

```
undefined reference to 'nids_run'
undefined reference to 'nids_register__tcp'
undefined reference to 'nids_init'
```

I know there is something wrong with 'linking to library'  but i don't know what's that!

I would like someone to guide me , how to fix this error

Comment: Can you give us some hints what is `libnids` ?

Comment: libnids is network intrusion detection system E-box library http://linux.die.net/man/3/libnids

Answer (score 0):

Well, better late than never.

You'll need to install libnids header files, and the dev libs as well. I suggest that you download them with a packet manager (like *yum* or *apt-get*).
Ex.:

```
sudo yum install libnids libnids-devel
```

Then, on Eclipse: Right click on you project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Linker > Includes

Then you'll include the nids library, with the name *nids*. If you're using just C, put it on GCC C Compiler.